# Nullable object must have a value while pass in stored procedure

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, model-view-controller, nullable

I am trying to send `ClearDateC` as parameter to procedure but it throwing an error

> nullable object must have value.

My code:

```
foreach (var item in bankRecos)
{
   DataTable Dt ;

   DateTime ChqDateC = Convert.ToDateTime(item.ChqdateDisplay);

   Dt = MD.GetBankReco_GetBankRecoUpdate(item.CommentC, (DateTime)item.ClearDateC, item.Chqno, ChqDateC);

   if (Dt.Rows.Count > 0 && Dt.Rows[0]["Status"].ToString() == "1")
   {
       status = "Success";
   }
   else
   {
       status = "Error : " + Dt.Rows[0]["Message"].ToString().Replace('\n', '_');
   }
}
```

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the call to check if the nullable DateTime filed has value and then use the `Value` property like

```
var cleardate = item.ClearDateC.HasValue ? (DateTime)item.ClearDateC : DateTime.Now;
MD.GetBankReco_GetBankRecoUpdate(item.CommentC, cleardate, item.Chqno, ChqDateC);
```